# Customizing GNOME Shell animations

Tags: gnome, animations

How do I change/edit the animations in GNOME Shell? For example, I want to use the "Glide" animation for opening applications but GNOME Shell uses "Fade". Any way I can do that?

Comment: I've noticed a couple of themes on gnome-look.org such as [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/%5BANIMATED%5D+Mayur?content=143185) which claim to have customized animations. Perhaps the answer lies in modifying theme files? I wouldn't know a lot about this, but perhaps someone else can come up with a more detailed answer on how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, Gnome Shell if that's what you're referring to by "Gnome 3" uses Mutter for compositing, and the "Glide" visual effect is only available in "Compiz", and no you can't use Compiz with Gnome Shell.